# Can a negative radical be expressed in terms of positive radical?

Tags: radicals

I want to get rid of negative radicals, but I guess this is not possible. Assume I have:

$$-\sqrt{c}$$

Where $c$ is from $\mathbb Q^+$. Can I express this as follows, where a and b are from $\mathbb Q^+$:

$$-a + \sqrt{b}$$

Comment: Why stop at negative radicals? Why not just get rid of negative numbers?

Comment: I need negative numbers for -a. I edited the question to use $\mathbb Q^+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\sqrt{c}=-a + \sqrt{b}$$
$$c=a^2 -2a\sqrt{b} + b$$

This could happen, but only when at least $\sqrt{b}$ is a rational number, and thus $\sqrt{c}$ has to be a rational number as well - not an interesting case.

Comment: So its not possible when $\sqrt{c}$ is irrational?

Comment: @j4nbur53 no, it's not possible, because the right-hand side is a rational due to $\sqrt{b}$ being a rational.